# Send email from Google Sheet when cell is is =1 by using apps script

Tags: dataframe, google-sheets, spreadsheet, sendmail

Send email,

I am trying to create a send email script, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24cnM.png), any cell in H column reach to 1 send me email with a certain message, any support from anyone. I already out the email with the email in the sheet.

I am trying to use this script,

```js
    function ifstatement() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1"); 
      var value = sheet.getRange("b2").getValue(); 
      if(value >= "1") sendEmail(value) 
    }; 
    
    function sendEmail(value){ 
      var recipient="tarek.jabboury@gmail.com"; 
      var subject=" test subject " +value; 
      var body=" test body "+value; 
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
    }
```

Comment: Would you please clarify how the values in Column H are determined? By data entry, or formula result? The answer will affect the type of trigger. Also, say row#4 = 1 and the email is sent; how would you propose to ensure that only one email is ever sent for this user?

Comment: The data from Column H coming from a Sum formula, Row # 4 contain if formula, if H = or < 1 will tell me Renew, I will use my email to all users to know who will finish to remind him.

Comment: `I am trying to create a send email script` Great, so would you please edit the question to include the script that you have written so far.

Comment: I am trying to use this script,

function ifstatement() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var value = sheet.getRange("b2").getValue();
  if(value >= "1") sendEmail(value)



};

function sendEmail(value){
  var recipient="tarek.jabboury@gmail.com";
  var subject=" test subject " +value;
  var body=" test body "+value;
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);

Comment: I suggest that you don't display your "real" email address

Comment: I want to be VERY clear about the values in **Column H**. Are these values entered by a user, or are they the results of a formula?

Comment: Iam receiving this error
11:42:32 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Range')
sendEmail @ Code.gs:8

The function below is working well

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77852981/send-email-from-google-sheet-when-cell-is-is-1-by-using-apps-script/77864697#77864697:~:text=function%20ifstatement(,recipient%2C%20subject%2C%20body)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D

But the result is still missing, I need to receive email if any cell in column H =1 with subject include the data from A,B and h.

Comment: “with subject include the data from A,B and h”. This was NOT part of the question. Please edit the question to explain how the spreadsheet values are used in the email.

Comment: I am sorry that my answer did not meet your expectations. I hope that another user can assist you.

Comment: Thank You Mr. Tedinoz I appreciate your try

Answer (score 0):

You want to send an email IF the value in Column H is changed to 1.

The script needs an installable `onEdit` trigger.

- this enables the script to be automatically triggered when a user changes a value in Column H
- tests for the correct sheet, column and value
- uses [Event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#google_apps_triggers) to provide key data values

---

```
// this function will send an email if the user enters 1 in Column H
// an installable "onEdit" trigger must be created to trigger the function

function sendEmail(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))

  var editedValue=e.value
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet().getName()
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  Logger.log("DEBUG: column  = "+editedCol+" , value ="+editedValue+" & sheet = "+editedSheet)
  // test for a change in 
  // sheet1, Column H, value = 1

  if (editedCol != 8 || editedValue != 1 || editedSheet != "Sheet 1"){
    // ignore the edit; wrong column, value or sheet
    Logger.log("DEBUG: ignore the edit")
    return
  }
  else{
    var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
    var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(editedSheet).getRange(editedRow,2).getValue() // get value of cell B2
    var recipient="ejb@tedbell.com.au"
    var subject=" test subject " +value 
    var body=" test body "+value
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
    Logger.log("Mail sent")
  }
}
```

Comment: Iam receiving this error
11:42:32 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Range')
sendEmail @ Code.gs:8

The function below is working well

Comment: Iam receiving this error
11:42:32 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Range')
sendEmail @ Code.gs:8

The function below is working well

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77852981/send-email-from-google-sheet-when-cell-is-is-1-by-using-apps-script/77864697#77864697:~:text=function%20ifstatement(,recipient%2C%20subject%2C%20body)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D

But the result is still missing, I need to receive email if any cell in column H =1 with subject include the data from A,B and h. From the same raw

Comment: How are you running the function? You don’t run it from the Editor, it is designed to run automatically when a user edits a value of ‘1’ in Column H. Have you created the installable trigger?

Comment: check this question please :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77875866/i-need-to-receive-email-if-any-cell-in-column-h-1-with-subject-include-the-data